# Trouble applying a user-defined string replace function to contents of a tibble

Tags: r, function, dataframe, tibble

I have a user-defined function to replace text patterns. This seems to work on a data frame but not a tibble.

```
fixcontents <- function(mydf, mypattern1, mypattern2, mycol) {
  mydf[ ,mycol] <- sub(mypattern1, mypattern2, mydf[ ,mycol])
  return(mydf)
}

mydf1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(1,2), col2 = c("aaa", "bbb"))
mytbl1 <- tibble(col1 = c(1,2), col2 = c("aaa", "bbb"))

fixcontents(mydf1, "(b{3})", "\\1X", 2) # works
mydf1

  col1 col2
1    1  aaa
2    2 bbbX

fixcontents(mytbl1, "(b{3})", "\\1_", 2) # does not work (??)
mytbl1

# A tibble: 2 x 2
   col1 col2 
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 aaa  
2     2 bbb
```

Why this behavior, and how do you manipulate data in a tibble?

Comment: Have you loaded the tidyverse package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subsetting using `[` works differently on tibbles. Subsetting dataframe returns a vector whereas tibble returns tibble back.

```
mydf1[, 2]
#[1] aaa bbb
#Levels: aaa bbb

mytbl1[, 2]
# A tibble: 2 x 1
#  col2 
#  <chr>
#1 aaa  
#2 bbb
```

Try using `[[` to subset

```
fixcontents <- function(mydf, mypattern1, mypattern2, mycol) {
  mydf[[mycol]] <- sub(mypattern1, mypattern2, mydf[[mycol]])
  return(mydf)
}

fixcontents(mydf1, "(b{3})", "\\1X", 2)
#  col1 col2
#1    1  aaa
#2    2 bbbX

fixcontents(mytbl1, "(b{3})", "\\1_", 2)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#   col1 col2 
#  <dbl> <chr>
#1     1 aaa  
#2     2 bbb_
```

Comment: The replacement seems to work. However, one problem I am having is that the actual data object is not being updated. So running the function produces outputs the expected result, but my original tibble (or data frame) is not modified. What am I missing

Comment: @marcel You need to assign the output of the function to the object back `mydf1 <- fixcontents(mydf1, "(b{3})", "\\1X", 2)`